# Program won't run when using java.util.Arrays -- what might be going wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I get a bunch of errors when the code within the "clearPets" method is not commented out. As long as I delete that code, the program will run otherwise.

How can the problems be fixed? I've only recently learned about creating and calling methods, and this is my first time using `java.util.Arrays`.

The errors in the console are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Boolean
at java.util.Arrays.fill(Unknown Source)
at rf.uhh.clearPets(uhh.java:34)
at rf.uhh.optionOne(uhh.java:39)
at rf.uhh.main(uhh.java:20)
```

Here is the code I have:

```
public class uhh {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Select a number");
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);      
        String numberChoice = scnr.nextLine();

        if( "1".equals(numberChoice) ) {
            System.out.println("You chose 1");
            optionOne(new boolean[][] { {false}, {true} });
        }

        scnr.close();
    }   

    public static boolean[][] adoptPets( int cats, int dogs) {      
        boolean[][] pets = new boolean[cats][dogs];

        return pets ;
    }

    public static void clearPets( boolean[][]pets) {
        Arrays.fill(pets, false);
    }   

    public static void optionOne(boolean[][] center) {
        clearPets(center);

        boolean[][] dogFaceMan = adoptPets(10, 10);
        dogFaceMan[1][1] = true;                                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a 2D array into a method ([Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(boolean[],%20boolean))) that expects a 1D array.

Try this:

```
public static void clearPets( boolean[][]pets) {
    for(int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(pets[i], false);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works and makes perfect sense! I will accept this as the answer as soon as I'm able (stackoverflow time restriction).

Comment: @Neo no problem, glad to help.